# How to know if a java Mongo driver is compatible with a given Mongo Server?

Tags: java, mongodb, version

I am evaluation to upgrade my java-mongo-driver to 2.11.1 but I'm not sure if it's backwards compatible.

The [release notes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/wiki/Release-Notes) doesn't specify the compatibility of the driver, so I can't be sure if I need to update the production server.

Even-though my specific needs are to backwards compatible I would like to know if there is any convention between the driver version number and the mongo version that will give us a hint of its compatibility.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should. But if it's possible you may want to set up a test environment and make sure before you make changes on your production server. Although it's unlikely that it should break something.

Comment: What version are you upgrading from and what version of the server are you running?

Comment: I am running mongo 2.0.2 and will like to upgrade to mongo DB 2.4.3. Actually, I have already done it and it worked OOTB. However, I still don't know how to relate the compatibility of the driver with the mongo server.

Comment: I just tried using QueryBuilder of 2.10.0 java driver against a mongodb 1.8.2. It did not work with the db. When I replaced the QueryBuilder with a BasicDbObject it worked. I looked at the toString() of the two options and they did create different syntax. The QueryBuilder created db.mediation_filter_request_caps_coll.update({ "mediationFilterId" : 55892186 , "$and" : [ { "dayNum" : 15995}]}, { "$inc" : { "actVal" : 1}}) while the BasicDbObject created db.mediation_filter_request_caps_coll.update({ "mediationFilterId" : 55892186 , "dayNum" : 15995}, { "$inc" : { "actVal" : 1}}). Much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the compatibilities for drivers starting from 2.11 [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-java).
Basically the 2.11 version supports only MongoDB 2.4